# Почему не видна карта после загрузки апк на альфа тест

Tags: android, google-maps

Здравствуйте, после того как загрузил приложение на альфа тест в плей маркет, после скачивания не видна карта, хотя на эмуляторе и если загружаю через usb на телефон все видно, подскажите пожалуйста что делать

Comment: Попробуйте собрать релизный (Signed APK) и запустить его на эмуляторе. Скорее всего ключ API для карт у Вас только для debug. Нужно сгенерировать еще один для релизной сборки.

Comment: @VladimirPerfenov а для этого требуются те же действия, что и для дебага?

Comment: Да. В консоли разработчика. Сгенерируйте ключ и добавьте в проект.